# Check If String Remains Same After Rotating Left Or Right N Places

Tags: string, algorithm

Suppose we have a string "bcb".

```
If we rotate it 1 place  left, it becomes "cbb", 
  which is not the same as the original. 
If we rotate it 2 places left, it becomes "bbc", 
  which is not the same as the original. 
If we rotate it 3 places left, it becomes "bcb", 
  which IS the same as the original.
```

What is best way to find if a string remains same after rotating it `n` places left or right?

Comment: You could have a loop iterating through the string n times (where n is the length of the string).  Though, by the time you reach n, you'll have a match.  Are you trying to find a match before the string has shifted to its original position?

Comment: in my case input would be "bbc" & 2...output false... another input "bcb" & 3...output true...how can i get the output

Comment: Edit: Oh, I see.  What language are you using?

Comment: language agnostic solution i m looking for...otherwise java is preferred

Comment: @bbshaw see if my answer answers your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if the rotated string is still the same as original you will have to loop through the string characters and check if `rotated number` **+** `index` you are looping of string is you same for all the characters for string length. If it is not then return `false` else `true`

Here is the small Python code snippet for reference:

```
sample_str = 'bcb'
num_rotation = 6

def checkSimilarity(str, num_rotation):
  length = len(str)
  for i in range(length):
    if(sample_str[i] != sample_str[(num_rotation + i)%length]):
      return False
  return True

print(checkSimilarity(sample_str, num_rotation))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does that loop exit after it finds something isn't the same?  My experience with python is very minimal.

Comment: well in my snippet it wont, but yes it can if you make it a function and return False and true otherwise it will exit.

Comment: I can make a function out of it also if you want

Comment: Okay, was just making sure.  If you did have it exit, that'd boost efficiency slightly.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, but I just added the snipped more of an idea on how to check the same. I'll update the answer for the same

Comment: ur solution looks good to me...i hav a solution...can u plz see if theres a case where it wont work...if i split the string by length of rotation number...suppose i hav ababab...if rotation number is 2...then i will get ab, ab & ab...i will check if all the splits are same...if yes its true otherwise false

Comment: @bbshaw As far as I can think of, I think yes your approach is also correct, but in your case you might have to split that many strings then check all for equality, which will only consume more memory and if you compare from this code complexity.

Comment: Also in case of odd length string and if rotation is let's say only 2 and Len of STR is 5 this will create uneven number of string splits then you will have to check for equality . It's just more calculations and conditions

Comment: @warl0ck yeah...my solution will have some unwanted overhead

Answer (score 2):

Concatenate the string to itself (length `2n`).  Step through the resulting string in `n`-length slices, looking for a match.

```
double = orig + orig
orig_len = length(orig)
for i in [1:orig_len]
    if double[i:i+orig_len] == orig
        print "success at index", i
```

If your implementation language has a built-in substring search, use that instead of this loop.

Comment: Or maybe use a regex matcher to test orig vs {double minus its first and last elements}, which is optimized for such things.

Answer (score 0):

Have two indexes into the string. Start one at the first character, and start the second at the nth character. Now, compare character-by-character.

You need to handle the wraparound case for the second index, but that's no trouble.

Pseudocode:

```
mystring = "bcbc"
ix1 = 0
ix2 = n mod mystring.length
while (ix1 < mystring.length)
    if mystring[ix1] != mystring[ix2]
        return false
    ++ix1
    ix2 = (ix2 + 1) mod mystring.length
end while
return true
```

If you rotate one space to the left, this will return false. Two spaces, it will return true.